# AutoSuggestBox in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

My application is using a DataGrid. Some of the fields in the DataGrid are editable.

Rather than have the user type anything they want into the editable fields, I want to use an AutoSuggestBox. I have used AutoSuggestBox controls on their own, but I don't know how to incorporate one into a DataGrid. Is this possible?

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the AutoSuggestBox by custom **CellTemplate** from Column  like below:

```
<controls:DataGrid ItemsSource="{x:Bind lists}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">​
                <controls:DataGrid.Columns>​
                    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">​
                        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>​
                            <DataTemplate>​
                                <AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="hello" Width="100"></AutoSuggestBox>​
                            </DataTemplate>​
                        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>​
                    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>​
                </controls:DataGrid.Columns>​
</controls:DataGrid>
```